# Getting GITHUB Users list

Tags: git, api, github, postman

I want to get all users list named as abcde using below in postman

https://api.github.com/search/users?q=abcde+repos:%3E1&

it says there are 174 but i only get default 30

I also used curl

`curl --location --request GET 'https://api.github.com/search/users?q=abcde+repos:%3E1' | jq '.items[].login'`

but here also got 30, how can i get all 174 names ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is paginated.  If you check the response headers, it gives links to the next page:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
date: Tue, 09 Jun 2020 09:39:47 GMT
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
server: GitHub.com
status: 200 OK
cache-control: no-cache
x-github-media-type: github.v3; format=json
link: <https://api.github.com/search/users?q=abcde+repos%3A%3E1&page=2>; rel="next", <https://api.github.com/search/users?q=abcde+repos%3A%3E1&page=6>; rel="last"
access-control-expose-headers: ETag, Link, Location, Retry-After, X-GitHub-OTP, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-OAuth-Scopes, X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes, X-Poll-Interval, X-GitHub-Media-Type, Deprecation, Sunset
access-control-allow-origin: *
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload
x-frame-options: deny
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
referrer-policy: origin-when-cross-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin
content-security-policy: default-src 'none'
vary: Accept-Encoding, Accept, X-Requested-With, Accept-Encoding
X-Ratelimit-Limit: 10
X-Ratelimit-Remaining: 8
X-Ratelimit-Reset: 1591695621
Accept-Ranges: bytes
X-GitHub-Request-Id: xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

If you check above, there is a `link` header, its value is `link: <https://api.github.com/search/users?q=abcde+repos%3A%3E1&page=2>; rel="next", <https://api.github.com/search/users?q=abcde+repos%3A%3E1&page=6>; rel="last"`
. which gives next pages link.  You can follow that.

Comment: Thanks, how can i use it as a loop in curl, till page 6

Comment: This link will help:  https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/traversing-with-pagination/

Comment: Basically you will need iterative curl, or a bash script.

Comment: You are welcome!  If you feel the answer good, pls upvote and accept as answer to help others as well.